# How to use regexp in windows batch file to start a installation?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

My Windows batch file:

```
@echo off

    start C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_windows_x32_1_67_87_TEST %1"-Fenv=http://test.com/test"
```

I am starting exe file installation with some environment settings using the above batch script. Its working as expected.

But in the above batch file, I am giving full name "test_windows_x32_1_67_87_TEST". But I wanted to start the installation if the file starts with "test_windows".

Please guide me how I can use regular expression in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) to enumerate the files matching `test_windows*`:

```
for %%a in (C:\Users\test\Desktop\test_windows*) do (
    start "" "%%a" %1"-Fenv=http://test.com/test"
    goto done
)
:done
```

P.S. the code exits the loop after the first match just in case there are many such files, but if it's impossible you can remove `goto done` and `:done` lines.